# BOOST shared pointer causes redundant reference delete

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

I have the following app structure :

```
/// CLASS VIEW3D.h
class View3D;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<View3D>     ViewSP;
class View3D
{

public:
   View3D(void);


    };

/// CLASS SCREENQUAD.h

 class ScreenQuad
{
public:
    ScreenQuad(ViewSP view);

    ~ScreenQuad(void);
    protected:
    ViewSP _viewSP;




};
/// CLASS VIEW3D.cpp
  View3D::Init(ViewSP view)

{

    _screenQuadSP=new ScreenQuad(view);

}
```

/// CLASS SCREENQUAD.cpp

```
 ScreenQuad::ScreenQuad(ViewSP view):

    _viewSP(view)           
{
    assert(_viewSP);

}
```

Now, I pass a reference of class `A` into class `B` in the form of shared pointer and keep it in a global variable `A_SP`. When the app shots down I am getting this:

```
HEAP:   Free Heap block 2837920 modified at 2837b5c after it was freed
```

After debugging the execution  I found that after the class `A` destructor has been called it gets called again when the destructor of class `B` is executed.So my guess is that the boost tries to free the memory at the address of the pointer encapsulated in `_A_ref`.
Just to note: the order of destruction is `A` class first, then `B` class.

How do I get around it? Shouldn't `shared_ptr` keep the ref count and not to trigger destructor of the object which has already been released?

Comment: Can you provide a short compilable example that reproduces the behaviour that you describe?

Comment: So many things wrong: semicolons are missing, leading underscore-capital names are reserved...

Comment: Ok ,it was just a pseudo code...

Comment: @MichaelIV: Pseudo code has pseudo errors. Please post real code. There's no point wasting everyone's time on something that *isn't* the problem.

Comment: Hope this looks better.

Comment: @Michael Nah, can't really reproduce this with the code you provided. I'm confused about your error description though: You seem puzzled why `A` is destructed 'again', whereas to me it seems that it shouldn't be destructed the first time round since there's still a shared pointer in `B` referencing it. So my first point of investigation would be: Why is A's destructor called even though there still is a shared_ptr pointing to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is still too incomplete the show the problem, but I can think of a few common causes for such an error.

- You explicitly `delete` your View3D instance somewhere. Don't do that, the `shared_ptr` will. If you no longer need the object, you can call `ptr.reset()`, which will decrease its reference count and delete it if appropriate. (This happens automatically when a `shared_ptr` is destroyed, e.g. in your `ScreenQuad` destructor; in that case there's no need to do it explicitly.)
- You accidentally created multiple reference counters for the same object. There should be only one spot where you create a `shared_ptr`from a `View3D*` raw pointer, namely at the same place where the object is created. Everywhere else, you have to create your shared pointers from other shared (or weak) pointers. Otherwise you'll end up with multiple reference counters, and each of these will eventually try to delete the object, even if it has been freed already.
- You created a `shared_ptr` to an object on the stack. Essentially, that's the same problem as calling `delete` on a stack-allocated object.

This might help you find the error yourself, otherwise you really need to post more code – as far as I can see nothing of this happens in the snippets you showed so far.

Comment: I suspect this is my problem : " You accidentally created multiple reference counters for the same object. There should be only one spot where you create a shared_ptrfrom a View3D* raw pointer, namely at the same place where the object is created."